# Kick make dead in goal line rugby

Tags: rugby-union

Attacking team kick a grubber in defending team in-goal area. Defending team does not choose to ground it but choose to run it out in deadball line or to kick it out in dead ballline. What sanction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sanction, these are entirely legitimate actions to put the ball out of play.

Play is restarted with a goal line drop-out under Law 12.12.a,

> Play is restarted with a goal line drop-out when:
>
> a. The ball is played or taken into in-goal by an attacking player and is then held up, grounded or otherwise made legally dead by an opponent.

If they instead knocked or threw the ball out of play, they would be sanctioned with a penalty under Law 9.7.b,

> 7. A player must not:
>
> ...
>
> b. Intentionally knock, place, push or throw the ball with arm or hand from the playing area.